# Lucene index files not getting deleted when reindexed

Tags: lucene

I am using lucene 4.7 version to index a table in the database. The index files are getting created starting with _0. However, when I re-run the same program to create indexes again, a new set of files are getting created starting with _1. I have set the IndexWriterConfig open mode to CREATE_OR_APPEND. Why are _0 files not getting deleted? This is creating a problem as whenever I reindex from that huge table, the folder size is getting doubled.

Comment: I have tried, indexWriter.deleteUnusedFiles() as well, but it never worked. I am using a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fully reindex, you can use open mode: `CREATE`, rather than `CREATE_OR_APPEND`.  If you open with the latter in the same directory, it will open the existing index in append mode.  If you then add the same documents all over again while reindexing, you will end up with two copies of each document in the index.  Opening in `CREATE` mode will delete the old index found in the given directory, and you can reindex from scratch. (see the [`IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode` documentaiton](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.html))

You can also [update Documents](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20java.lang.Iterable%29), if you desire, though if you are intending to recreate the whole index, the performance will be significantly poorer than simply opening in create mode and adding documents.

Comment: Hey thanks that helped. I was trying to use CREATE_OR_APPEND mode.